# React.js Recommended Assigning `props` Directly To State

Tags: reactjs, warnings, react-props, react-component, react-state

A React.js warning was thrown:

> IndexPage: It is not recommended to assign props directly to state because updates to props won't be reflected in state. In most cases, it is better to use props directly.

I had the following code:

```
    class IndexPage extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = props
       }
    }
```

But, when I have changed my code to:

```
    class IndexPage extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {...props}
       }
    }
```

The warning's gone.

Can you please explain why?

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of how JS assignment of object values works, assigning one object to another means that the second variable will "point" to the same instance, or hold a reference to it:

```
let x = { v: 1 };
let y = x;
x.v = 2;
console.log(y.v) // prints "2"
```

The warning is there to prevent accidental assumptions about the props being automatically "propagated" to the state. IOW, it doesn't just work like you'd normally expect:

```
// assume props = { v: 1 };
this.state = props;
// now props changes to { v: 2 };
console.log(this.state.v) // still prints 1, and that's why you get the warning
```

The warning goes away because by destructuring, you're making it obvious that a new object is being created, and you don't expect the state to have the same value as props when they change.