# Cannot use a react component with git clone but can use it using npm install

Tags: reactjs

I would like to use the following component
https://github.com/plotly/react-pivottable

It works well if I use npm install react-pivottable and other dependencies has specified on the above page.
If I try to clone the repository to make changes(so far I didn't make any but plan to)
if I do the simple example they provided but importing from the git clone:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PivotTableUI from './react-pivottable/src/PivotTableUI';
import './react-pivottable/src/pivottable.css';

// see documentation for supported input formats
const data = [['attribute', 'attribute2'], ['value1', 'value2']];

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = props;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <PivotTableUI
                data={data}
                onChange={s => this.setState(s)}
                {...this.state}
            />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

I will get many errors such as :

```
Warning: App: It is not recommended to assign props directly to state because updates to props won't be reflected in state. In most cases, it is better to use props directly.
    in App (at src/index.js:26)
or
uncaught Sortable: `el` must be an HTMLElement, not [object Object]
It @ sortable.complete.esm.js:521
...
index.js:1437 The above error occurred in the <It> component:
    in It (at PivotTableUI.jsx:344)
    in tr (at PivotTableUI.jsx:539)
    in tbody (at PivotTableUI.jsx:530)
    in table (at PivotTableUI.jsx:529)
    in PivotTableUI (at src/index.js:17)
    in App2 (at src/index.js:26)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

None of these appears if I only do npm-install of the component.
It is my first time trying to git clone a component to make some modifications on it and I am probably doing something wrong, any idea?

EDIT:

removing or changing the this.state = props
will just remove the warning, other errors will remain. Note that the above code is not mine it is the example provided almost as is except the imports to point to where i cloned the code. None of the above warnings/errors appears if I import directly after npm install

Comment: If you really want to set `state` from `props`, do `this.state = { ...props}` instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering, as I wrote below, doing what you mention will remove the warning but the rest of the errors will stay. that part is not something I wrote and the warning won't even appear if I do npm install and use the component directly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that

```
  this.state = props;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I previously tried by curiosity, it will remove the warning but not the other errors and since it was on their example file I decided to keep it the code as close as possible as their example.

Comment: You can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877957/it-is-not-recommended-to-assign-props-directly-to-state-because-updates-to-props

Comment: The question is still valid whether this.state = props, the line is removed or fixed doing this.state = { ...props}. Code provided above is just provided as is from their website and is working fine if using npm install

Comment: This isn't really an answer as it fails to address the issue OP has with third-party module, it just duplicates a comment. If you believe it to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877957/it-is-not-recommended-to-assign-props-directly-to-state-because-updates-to-props then flag it as such.